Sufficient condition for simulation of $A^{B}$ by $C$
The task is to show $A^{B}\subseteq C$, where, $A,\ B$ and $C$ are complexity classes.
Is (i) $A\subseteq C$, (ii) $B\subseteq C$ and, (iii) $B$=co-$B$ are sufficient conditions to deduce $A^{B}\subseteq C$?
Or is there a counter-example to it?

My motivation: the assumption $P^{NP}\subseteq NP$ implies NP=co-NP. I want to see if the converse holds true or not. And if it can be generalized to classes beyond P and NP.

$A^B$ is not an object uniquely defined from $A$ and $B$. Hence you cannot infer the inclusion you want from any property of $A$.

$\mathrm{NP=coNP}$ does imply $\mathrm{P^{NP}=NP}$, but because of more specific properties of these classes.

@EmilJeřábek, (as always) thanks! I tried building the generalization based on the intuition from the "special case" of P, NP, and $P^{NP}$. I will be happy if you can help me build a counter-example for the general case of A, B, and $A^{B}$. Thanks!

As usual, these kind of things are very hard to construct. But let $X$ be an oracle such that $\mathrm P^X\ne\mathrm{NP}^X$; I think one can modify the usual proofs of their existence to show that, additionally, $X$ can be found with arbitrarily large complexity, in particular, we can assume $X$ is NP-hard. Put $A=\mathrm{NP}$ and $B=C=\mathrm P^X$. Then $A\subseteq C$, $B\subseteq C$, $B=\mathrm{co}B$ (even $B=\mathrm P^B$), but “$A^B$”, i.e., $\mathrm{NP}^X$, is not included in $C$.

But really, the question as formulated does not make sense. Once again: the notation $A^B$ has no meaning for arbitrary complexity classes $A$ and $B$. It is only defined when $A^{\dots}$ denotes a class of oracle Turing machines (or similar relativized devices), in which case $A^B$ is defined as the languages computed by such things when the oracle is taken from $B$, and the “class $A$” as such is defined as $A^\varnothing$. There is no general way of going in the opposite direction, from a complexity class $A$ to a class of relativized devices.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12480/for-complexity-classes-a-and-b-what-does-ab-mean#comment351260_12480
